# magento - bilingual store - limit display of category tabs (menus)

Tags: categories, magento-1.8

**Desired behavior:**  I would like to see a Welcome Category Tab on French Store View, Bienvenue Category Tab on French store View

**Actual Behavior:** I get both English and French tabs (menus) in both stores!

**Methodology:**

I set up two store views (which works OK for all other translation requirements).

I set up two CMS static blocks - for 1) English store view 2) french store view.

Then I set up two categories - 1) Welcome 2) Bienvenue

For Each Category, in Display Settings, I set:

- Display Mode = static block only
- CMS = my language

**Problem:** I can make text language specific, but I don't know how to only show category tab for  the appropriate Store View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was right there in Category Setup Page!

In Category Setup Page, in Upper left hand corner, select store that you don't want to show category, specify "Is Active" = No

Unwanted tab is now gone.

Repeat for each category as required.